# Is it possible to call a function of __init__.py from views.py in django?

Tags: python, django, view, function-call

**init**.py :

```
def abc():
    some code
```

views.py:

```
from . import __init__

__init__.abc()
```

This gives error
`AttributeError: 'method-wrapper' object has no attribute 'abc'`

Is it possible to call the abc() function from views.py ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__.py` is a special file which is the root of your package.

Thus, you have to do:

```py
from . import abc

abc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it in views.py:

```
# Import your function
from .__init__ import abc
# Run your function in code
abc()
```